# VueJS Webpack where to add plugins

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to add **web pack** **provided Plugins** to use JQuery globally.
Some articles says

> You need to put it in webpack.config.js under plugins:[]

But when I look at my `webpack.config.js` there is no such `plugins` object.
Then I create `plugins` object manually under the `module` array.

After that when I try to run the project using npm run dev

it doesn't run.
I want to add this plugin to the `webpack.config.js`

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
})
```

How do I do this?
This is my webpack.config.js file

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins[
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  Vue: ['vue/dist/vue.esm.js', 'default']
})


],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a quick look at the webpack documentation for plugins [here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/plugins/#configuration), you would see where the `plugins` object belongs.

The good news is: your webpack config already looks correct - you put the plugins array as a direct child of the config, after `module`, instead of inside it. You only miss a `:` colon after `plugins`, which likely is a typo.

So I don't see a reason what should not work.

Comment: =) That may the reason. But even If I correct that thing even after that it doesn't work. It gives me the error Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' I import JQuery as a CDN in in my index.html. Do I need to install JQuery as npm

Answer (score 0):

Try this in **build/webpack.dev.conf.js** and **build/webpack.prod.conf.js**:

```
plugins: [

  // ...

  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
]
```

jQuery becomes globally available to all your modules:

Comment: Where is the build folder I'm unable to find it in my project. I use webpack-simple. Is that the reason? I have a dist folder. But there is no such a webpack.prod.conf.js file.

Comment: try it in the webpack.config.js folder

Comment: That is my question, there is no place called plugins when I create that one manually and try to run project doesn't run. See my webpack.config.js file